# boost::typeindex::type_id<>().pretty_name() differences for different systems/compilter/boost-versions?

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to run a project where `boost::typeindex::type_id<>().pretty_name()` is used to transform the classname to a string, to register it in a factory.

For example class A should transform to `"A"`, class B to `"B"`, etc.

This is working in a Linux gcc environment by using `boost::typeindex::type_id<A>().pretty_name()`.

When I try to run the project in Windows with MSVC 14 and Boost 1.78.0 however class names are transformed in this way:

class A transforms to `"class A"`, class B transforms to `"class B"`, and so on...

Is this because of the OS differences or the compiler differences or some boost parameters or boost version differences?

Comment: `boost::typeindex::type_id<A>()` is meant to be used directly as hashable type index. It has type `boost::typeindex::type_index`. Although it doesn't actually seem clear to me what guarantees the library makes e.g. for uniqueness of type index. Consider using `std::type_index` instead to have some more guarantees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost’s [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_typeindex/how_it_works.html) state this library is just a wrapper for [std::type_info](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) which is purely implementation-dependent, notice how the example on cppreference corresponds to your case.